# Уконтропупить

Tags: этимология

И еще о происхождении слов. Есть шуточное слово "уконтропупить" (то есть, убить, укокошить). А какое слово легло в его основу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это окказиональное образование, прямых связей не имееющее. 
Но можно предположить, что в основе - операция контрирования (закрепление подвижного элемента долнительным устройством). Отсюда - контргайка.
Если все так, то логично написание укотрапупить, в каком виде и вошло в словари.

Другая версия - [тут](http://ria.ru/spravka/20111215/517428637.html). Но надо заметить, что значение слова подается явно усеченно. Это следует даже из примеров из Высоцкого и Маяковского. Подходит только к цитате из Зощенко